# AWS Route 53 Domain not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, dns, amazon-route53

I want to connect a domain to my EC2 instance via the Route 53 service I set up 4 days ago. I have followed the documentation and the dig-interface shows the correct output, but when I try to access it in the browser, it sais the host can't be resolved. What have I configured wrong?

Domain: http://yet-another-blog.com
IP of the server: 52.59.214.55

---

Route 53 configuration:

[image]

---

digwebinterface.com result:

[image]

Comment: Perform a dig on your local machine, what does that show. Validate what your DNS resolution shows

Comment: I get the same result on my local machine and the results match the entries specified in aws @mokugo-devops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the NS record of your domain it shows different nameservers than what is defined in your public zone.

It seems you created another public zone after you registered the domain or in a different AWS account.

Simply to solve this update the nameservers in the registrar to match the one in your public zone

Comment: "If you check the whois of your domain it shows different nameservers" whois is not authoritative on DNS data, the DNS is authoritative on DNS data. To find out nameservers of a domain you should do DNS queries, nothing else.

Comment: Correct, I actually meant a public whois website which also bring the DNS nameserver so you can know both at the same time.

Comment: Still no. Whois is not the tool to use to debug DNS problems (except in one specific case about "hold" status), even if a whois output shows the nameservers (in most cases but not all). To find out the nameservers of a domain you do not need a website, nor whois. You need just to do DNS queries, like with `dig`. Besides whois is a dying service, to be replaced by RDAP (but the above applies equally to RDAP as to whois). DNS troubleshooting is with DNS queries.

Comment: You totally missed my point. You need `dig` to get DNS records but can you tell me how to get registrar information with `dig`?

Comment: I totally missed your point, yet you edited your question to remove what was explicitly wrong as I discussed in earlier comments. Ok.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like yet-another-blog.com does not resolve because there’s no nameserver for that domain.

If you own this domain you’ll need to make sure it’s nameserver is set to target amazons name servers.

Making a public hosted zone isn’t enough.